# Connection Error with SQL Azure and Entity Framework on Azure Website

Tags: sql, entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database

Not sure where to start, but whenever I publish my ASP.NET website to Azure, any pages which have database access give me a message saying "Error. An Error occurred while processing your request." I open up the remote debugger (which is fickle because it refuses to attach half of the time) and I see the error occurs when establishing when trying to access Entity Framework. The error varies between a "network-related or instance-specific" error, or a "Login Failed" error (which could be the result of the previous error, I really don't know).

The ADO.NET connection string SQL Azure gives is

```
Server=tcp:[servername].database.windows.net,1433;Database=EnsembleMusicWebDatabase;User ID=user@[servername];Password=(password);Trusted_Connection=False;Connection Timeout=30;
```

But every implementation (inserting that into EF metadata string, changing the server to data source...etc) still gives me the same login error

I'm pretty sure it's a problem with the connection string, but the infuriating part is that I've tried every possible combination I can think of (entity framework metadata, using the SQL Azure database ADO.NET connection strings in any possible way, changing the Azure website connection strings under the Config tab, using just a plain connection string...etc).

I've deleted and rebuilt the Entity Framework models at least 5 times, and every time I can successfully establish a connection to the server and it successfully reads my database and creates the correct models. I deploy the application to localhost and it works. The problem is when I publish, it cannot access the database and keeps giving me these login failed errors (the login details are the exact same as when I set up the EF model).

I think it might be something to do with the firewall, since I can access the DB locally with an approved firewall IP on the server config, but the website itself can't access the database (I have the enable azure services box ticked as well). I'm really at a loss for what to do now, because I just want the site (not any user, just the application) to fetch some data from the database and display it on the page, but I don't understand how this could be so complicated.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I tried every tutorial and example on msdn and I can't find any solutions on SO that work.

Thanks,
Shaun

Comment: If you deploy to localhost, are you using the azure database in your connection string, or a local SQL server?

Comment: Hi Shaun, can you please send me your subscription ID, server name and database name(s) at shantanu dot kurhekar at microsoft dot com?Thanks.

Comment: @ErikOppedijk I was using the Azure database in the string, and that worked locally because my local IP was approved by the server firewall. But the string wasn't correct for the published site so I ended up deleting everything and connecting them during the creation process, which unsurprisingly worked straight away.

Answer (score 0):

I realised that I somehow got into a complete mess with connection strings all over the place and the best way to fix it was just to start again. I deleted my Azure website and database instances, built the database first (created a correct login as well) and then when creating a new website Azure gave me the option to include the database I had just created. I now have a correct connection string that Azure generated, but to be safe (because the metadata made connection strings confusing and I didn't want to risk having this same issue again) I'm not using Entity Framework and just using normal SqlClient queries, since the website only requests two objects from a database.

I think now I've got a correct and working string I can look at it and really understand where I went wrong and how to avoid this if I do end up using Entity Framework.